# Transactional Emails: Where does $this->getValueProperties() get its values from?

Tags: magento-1.7, email, email-templates

I am trying to edit the `totals` portion of a transactional email. I have found the file it refers to:

`/app/design/frontend/our_theme/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml`

which has this code:

```
<td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
  <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
    <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
  <?php else:?>
    <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
  <?php endif?>
</td>
```

The call to `$this->getValueProperties()` is inserting some inline CSS padding and a colspan to this table cell. I can't seem to figure out where it is getting these values from?

For example, the email output is as so:

```
<td style="padding:3px 9px" align="right">
  <span>€PRICE</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are set in the layout file. Check `sales.xml`. You should find inside the handle `<sales_email_order_items>` this line:

```
<action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Understanding Magento's layout xml system is quite a challenge and something I hope to eventually grasp.